# Distinguished triangles formed from fiber product of a morphism

Tags: category-theory, triangulated-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a triangulated category and $f:A\to B$ be morphism with fiber product $F\to A$. I have heard that this leads to a distinguished triangle of the form $$F\to A\to B\to\Sigma F$$ but I'm not sure what the morphism $B\to\Sigma F$ should be, or why such a triangle would necessarily be distinguished. In the case I am working with, I have shown that the fiber map $F\to A$ is zero, and need to show that the map $A\to B$ is a split monomorphism. Any help much appreciated.

Reason for asking is that I am trying to understand why $Y$ is a retract of $I$ towards the end of Proposition 2.2 in the following paper. https://academic.oup.com/qjmath/article/58/1/31/1561269

Comment: Which triangulated category are you working with exactly? General triangulated categories do not have the necessary limits to have fiber products. Is your $\mathcal{C}$ the homotopy category of something, and are you then taking pullbacks in the overlying category?

Comment: @DaniëlApol I see your point. These are stable homotopy categories (as defined in Axiomatic Stable Homotopy Theory: https://bookstore.ams.org/memo-128-610#:~:text=It%20starts%20with%20axioms%20defining,representability%2C%20to%20name%20a%20few. 

They are necessarily complete, and the pullbacks are taken in $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: When you say that $F\to A$ is the fiber product, do you then mean that $F$ is the pullback of $0\to A\xleftarrow{f} B$, i.e. how you normally would define kernels in pointed categories? Because then $F$ will not be part of a distinguished triangle as shown in general. If we let $\mathcal{C}$ be the homotopy category of spectra, and look at the map $f\colon 0\to \mathbb{S}$ (where $\mathbb{S}$ is the sphere spectrum) then the kernel in the homotopy category is just $F=0$, but $0\to 0 \to \mathbb{S} \to 0 $ is not a distinguished triangle in the homotopy category of spectra. (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) Instead, you would need to let $F$ be the _homotopy fiber_ of the map $f$, and this is not something you can compute in the homotopy category, but need to compute in the overlying (model/$\infty$-)category of spectra. Given Hovey's definition of stable model categories in his book on model categories, and given the situation in case of stable $\infty$-categories, I think I know how your question is supposed to be resolved, and then it would come down to $F$ actually not being the pullback in the homotopy category, but the homotopy pullback of the map $f$. Then you get a triangle.

Comment: @DaniëlApol It is actually the following paper https://academic.oup.com/qjmath/article/58/1/31/1561269 by Hovey which I am attempting to understand in relation to this. Towards the end of Proposition 2.2, he writes 'as there are no non-zero phantom maps to $Y$, $Y$ must be a retract of $I$'. It is in this context that I am interested in fibers, and I do not follow the quoted sentence.

Comment: Right, so as @DaniëlApol suggests, it's a homotopy fiber, not a fiber product. A bit more of that passage: "... the fiber $F \to Y$ of $Y \to I$ is a phantom map. Since there are no nonzero phantom maps to $Y$ ..." Combining these two says that the map $F \to Y$ is zero, so there is a fiber sequence $F \xrightarrow{0} Y \to I$. In any triangulated category, such an exact triangle means that $Y$ is a retract of $I$.

Comment: @user829347 A note on terminology: given a map $A\to B$ in a triangulated category, its _fiber_ is any object $F$ with a map $F\to A$ that is part of a distinguished triangle $F\to A\to B\to \Sigma F$. It is definitely not a fiber product in the triangulated category. In stable model categories, this fiber will however be modelled by the homotopy fiber of the map $A\to B$ in the model category _if_ your map $A\to B$ can be lifted to the model category. Likewise, the fiber will be modelled by an actual pullback in a stable $\infty$-category if you can lift $A\to B$ to this $\infty$-category.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri For $F\to Y\to I$ to form a triangle there needs to be a morphism $I\to\Sigma F$. What would the final morphism be and how do we know it is exact?

Comment: One of the axioms of a triangulated category is: given a map $Y \to I$, there exists an exact triangle $Y \to I \to Z \to \Sigma Y$. Let $F = \Sigma^{-1} Z$.

Answer (score 1):

With the extra information, I think we can put the discussion in the comments into an answer for clarity. (So this includes also John Palmieri's comments.)

Given a map $f\colon A\to B$ in a triangulated category $\mathcal{C}$, there is a distinguished triangle $F\to A\to B\to \Sigma F$ extending it, as is clear from the axioms. We call $F$ (or $F\to A$) the *fiber* of $f$. This means that, when working in a triangulated category, the fiber $F$ comes equipped also with a map $B\to \Sigma F$. (I will say later how this related to homotopy fibers in stable model/$\infty$-categories.)

Now, if $F\to A$ is the zero map, then indeed $A$ is a retract of $B$. Namely, in any triangulated category $\mathcal{C}$ a distinguished triangle $F\xrightarrow{q} A\xrightarrow{f} B\xrightarrow{p} \Sigma F$ gives you for any $X\in\mathcal{C}$ a long exact sequence
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\ldots@>>>[\Sigma F,X]@>{-\circ p}>>[B,X]@>{-\circ f}>>[A,X]@>{-\circ q}>>[F,X]@>>>[\Omega B,X]@>>>\ldots
\end{CD}
$$
of abelian groups, where $[-,-]\colon\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}\times\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}$ denotes the hom functor of $\mathcal{C}$. In particular, if $q=0$, then we see that $-circ f\colon[B,X]\to[A,X]$ is surjective, so taking $X=A$ and looking at the identity map $\mathrm{id}_A\in[A,A]$, we find a map $r\colon B\to A$ such that $rf=\mathrm{id}_A$, so $A$ is a retract of $B$.

The reason that in your example (so $\mathcal{C}=\mathrm{SHC}$ is the stable homotopy category) the map $F\to Y$ is a phantom map is because the map $Y\to I$ induces injections $[X,Y]\to [X,I]$ for all finite spectra $X$. This means that tha map $[X,F]\to[X,Y]$ must (in light of an analogous long exact sequence of hom groups) be the zero map for all finite spectra $X$. By Spanier-Whitehead duality (that is, the statement that all finite spectra are dualizable), this implies that on homology the map $F_*(X)\to Y_*(X)$ is the zero map for all finite spectra $X$. Since every spectrum is a filtered colimit of finite spectra, the map $F_*(X)\to Y_*(X)$ is even the zero map for *all* spectra $X$. In particular, the map is zero for all spaces $X$, so then $F\to Y$ is by definition a phantom map.

Now, let me finish by stating how you define distinguished triangles in the homotopy category of a stable model/$\infty$-category $\mathcal{M}$. Given a map $f\colon A\to B$ in $\mathcal{M}$, we can form its *homotopy fiber* $F$ as a homotopy pullback square
\begin{CD}
F@>>> A\\
@VVV @VV{f}V\\
0 @>>> B
\end{CD}
in $\mathcal{M}$. (Let me reiterate that $F$ is not the pullback in the homotopy category $\mathrm{Ho}(\mathcal{M})$.) The suspension of an object $X$ is defined via a homotopy pushout square
\begin{CD}
X@>>> 0\\
@VVV @VVV\\
0 @>>> \Sigma X
\end{CD}
Given a map $f\colon A\to B$ in $\mathcal{M}$, we would like to have a map $B\to \Sigma F$, where $F$ is the homotopy fiber of $f$. This is constructed by looking at the following diagram of homotopy pushouts (recall, in the stable setting homotopy pushouts and homotopy pullbacks coincide):
\begin{CD}
F @>>> A@>>> 0\\
@VVV @VV{f}V @VVV\\
0 @>>>B @>>{p}> C
\end{CD}
By homotopy pushout pasting, the large rectangle is also a homotopy pushout, so $C\simeq \Sigma F$. Therefore the map $p\colon B\to C\simeq \Sigma F$ is the map we are after.

It is only defined up to homotopy if we use this approach with homotopy pushouts, which is not a problem if $\mathcal{M}$ is a stable $\infty$-category. If $\mathcal{M}$ is a stable model category, then Hovey tends to assume his it is tensored over the category $\mathsf{sSet}$ of simplicial sets, giving him a functorial cone construction $X\mapsto (X\rightarrowtail CX)$ in  $\mathcal{M}$ (here, a cone on $X$ is a contractible object $CX$ together with a cofibration $X\rightarrowtail CX$). This allows him to actually be sure that the homotopy pushouts and pullbacks above exist, and he can then model them by strict pushout diagrams. In this case, $\Sigma F\cong CF\cup_F CF$, and $B\cong CF\cup _F A$,  and the map $B\to \Sigma F$ can be defined in $\mathrm{Ho}(\mathcal{M})$ as a composite $B\to B\cup_A CA \cong (CF\cup_F A)\cup_A CA\cong CF\cup_F CA \leftarrow CF\cup_F CF\cong\Sigma F$. Here, the last arrow $CF\cup_F CA \leftarrow CF\cup_F CF\cong\Sigma F$ goes the wrong way, but it is a weak equivalence, so it can be inverted in $\mathrm{Ho}(\mathcal{M})$. In a stable $\infty$-category, you don't need to assume extra structure, as you simply take the zero map $X\to 0$ to be a cone.

Now, the distinguished triangles in $\mathrm{Ho}(\mathcal{M})$ are by definition triangles that are isomorphic in $\mathrm{Ho}(\mathcal{M})$ to triangles of the form $F\to A\xrightarrow{f} B\to \Sigma F$, where $f\colon A\to B$ actually is a map in $\mathcal{M}$, and the other maps and objects are as we have defined them above.